# Sequence in Sql Server 2014 and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm working for a database from a legacy application. The database has a table called 'User' , with multiple records , the last of which id used is the value 900.
I need to implement a user registration form , and the id has to start 901. In Postgres , I just used a sequence and set the start value to 901 .
The problem is that the sql server has no sequence . How do I solve this problem with sql server and hibernate?

Thank you.

Comment: Old versions of Sql Server doesen't have sequences. 2014 has. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Have you tried AUTO_INCREMENT with the ID?

Comment: I am writing the getId with '@SequenceGenerator' and '@GeneratedValue', but gives error when starting the server : 
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect does not support sequences

Comment: I used the dialect org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect and works! Thanks anyway.

Comment: GenerationType.AUTO selects the most appropiate generation type appropiate for each database